# How to delay the process using ontimer function without using sleep()?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have to display 3 images in my application window, there should be 10 seconds of delay while displaying each image(i.e. each image should stay for 10 seconds).
How can i do this using ontimer() without using sleep().

Comment: What about [SetTimer()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49313fdf.aspx)  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ON_WM_TIMER()

```
SetTimer( TIMER_ID, 10000, NULL);
```

Here TIMER_ID you can pass any unique id.
10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds

```
void CYOURDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if(nIDEvent == TIMER_ID) // check timer Id
    {

        // Write your code to show exe

    }
    CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

This will call every 10 seconds as delay we have given 10 seconds.

you can call `KillTimer(TIMER_ID)` when you don't want to run timer.

Comment: The chain-back call at the end of CYOURDlg::OnTimer should be to the base class version of OnTimer (probably CDialog::OnTimer), not recursively to itself (your stack isn't big enough)